# How to make the horizontal scroll and section sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, transform

I have tried to achieve the horizontal scroll with mcustomscrollbar plugin but I want something how this website is doing https://www.happymaven.co.uk/ on the benefits fold, how can I make it sticky and unsticky after the scroll is done.

```
 var stickytl = $('.tl-section').offset().top;

 $(window).scroll(function() {  
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickytl) {
     $('.tl-section').removeClass('noscrolltl');
    $('.tl-section').addClass('scrolltl');

 }
 else {
    $('.tl-section').removeClass('scrolltl');
    $('.tl-section').addClass('noscrolltl');
 }  
});
```

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: Could you please attach a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @getSet I tried to add a class with sticky css and remove it but I am not able to figure how the Happymaven website is doing it

Comment: got the solution from https://codepen.io/KhaledPen/pen/YzXeXLm, I wonder how did I not find this answer from last 5 days